# Failed to flatten XML for resource 'invite_msg' with error: Invalid unicode escape sequence in string

Tags: android

iam tying to translate using the translate editor but keep on getting the following build error

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> C:\Users\Ralph\Documents\server apps \APPS \updated 25-10-2023\android updated 25-10-2023\app\src\main\res\values-fr\strings.xml:257:4: Failed to flatten XML for resource 'invite_msg' with error: Invalid unicode escape sequence in string
> "{str}"
> C:\Users\Ralph\Documents\server apps \APPS \updated 25-10-2023\android updated 25-10-2023\app\src\main\res\values-fr\strings.xml:257:4: string/invite_msg does not contain a valid string resource.

Here is the part code string error linge i translated with translation editor

```
<string name="legal_document">Document légal</string>
    <string name="stripe_details">Détails des rayures</string>
    <string name="submit">Soumettre</string>
    <string name="kanji_city">Ville</string>
    <string name="state_province_kanji">Etat/Province</string>
    <string name="postal_code_kanji">Code Postal</string>
    <string name="address_kana2">Adresse 2</string>
```

i tryed to look for the antislash mismarch but noting or any collor mismach spelling

Comment: do you have the `invite_msg` translation for *values-fr*?

Comment: no where can i find it please

Comment: your error log says `res\values-fr\strings.xml:257:4: string/invite_msg does not contain a valid string resource`

looks like it's missing